# WinForms layouts randomly screwed up

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have written several WinForms apps in my life, and every once in awhile something will go wrong with the layout at run-time. Today, while I was fiddling with the fonts in my application (mainly whether fonts were bold or not), I found that a control (which was anchored to all four sides of a TabPage) was extra-wide at runtime, going beyond the right edge of the page. I fiddled with the fonts again and the problem disappeared. Then I tried to replicate what I thought caused the problem in the first place, but it did not recur.

Another problem I sometimes have is that a Form with no MaximizeBox will randomly start maximized--maybe not on a development machine, but on a user's machine.

Can anyone tell me if they've had one of these problems and found the cause or solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are familiar with the `Anchor` and `WindowState` properties, and set them to the correct values.

Comment: I am. The Anchors are set correctly and I never touched WindowState in the app with the maximization problem (I'm sure I have seen the same problem in at least one app by a third party, I don't remember the name of it now.)

Comment: @Qwertie, try to set the WindowState manually when the form loads. My guess is that it is wrongly inherited from somewhere else.